# In python, changing MySQL query based on function variables

Tags: python, mysql, function

I'd like to be able to add a restriction to the query if user_id != None ... for example:

```
"AND user_id = 5"
```

but I am not sure how to add this into the below function?

Thank you.

```
def get(id, user_id=None):

    query = """SELECT *
               FROM USERS
               WHERE text LIKE %s AND
                     id = %s
            """
    values = (search_text, id)

    results = DB.get(query, values)
```

This way I can call:

```
get(5)
get(5,103524234) (contains user_id restriction)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def get(id, user_id=None):

    query = """SELECT *
               FROM USERS
               WHERE text LIKE %s AND
                     id = %s
            """
    values = [search_text, id]

    if user_id is not None:
        query += ' AND user_id = %s'
        values.append(user_id)

    results = DB.get(query, values)
```

As you see, the main difference wrt your original code is the small `if` block in the middle, which enriches query string and values if needed.  I also made `values` a list, rather than a tuple, so it can be enriched with the more natural `append` rather than with

```
         values += (user_id,)
```

which is arguably less readable - however, you can use it if you want to keep `values` a tuple for some other reasons.

**edit**: the OP now clarifies in a comment (!) that his original query has an ending `LIMIT` clause.  In this case I would suggest a different approach, such as:

```
   query_pieces = ["""SELECT *
                     FROM USERS
                     WHERE text LIKE %s AND
                         id = %s
                   """, "LIMIT 5"]
    values = [search_text, id]

    if user_id is not None:
        query_pieces.insert(1, ' AND user_id = %s')
        values.append(user_id)

    query = ' '.join(query_pieces)
    results = DB.get(query, values)
```

You could do it in other ways, but keeping a list of query pieces in the proper order, enriching it as you go (e.g. by `insert`), and joining it with some whitespace at the end, is a pretty general and usable approach.

Comment: What if I have a LIMIT = 5 at the end of the query, and I need to put this before that?

Comment: @ensnare, then you need a slightly different approach (and you need to ask your questions more specifically from the start;-) -- let me edit to show it.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with something like:

```
def get(id, user_id=None):
    query = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE text LIKE %s"
    if user_id != None:
        query = query + " AND id = %s"%(user_id)
    :
    :
```

That syntax may not be perfect, I haven't done Python for a while - I'm just trying to get the basic idea across. This defaults to the `None` case and only adds the extra restriction if you give a real user ID.

Answer (score 1):

You could build the SQL query using a list of conditions:

```
def get(id, user_id=None):
    query = """SELECT *
               FROM USERS
               WHERE 
            """
    values = [search_text, id]
    conditions=[
        'text LIKE %s',
        'id = %s']
    if user_id is not None:
        conditions.append('user_id = %s')
        values.append(user_id)
    query+=' AND '.join(conditions)+' LIMIT 1'
    results = DB.get(query, values)
```